# How to activate a WebGL streaming in matplotlib + PyQT5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

How to activate WebGl Streaming in PyQt?

I'm using matplotlib with PyQt5Agg backend. I installed last PyQt 5.12, python 3.6, Ubuntu 18, added `-platform webgl:port=8998`
as arguments, however nothing happens =(.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Out of "ingredients" only Qt QML-based app maters. With such statement not even sure if the author had such app and then tried http://localhost:8998 to open in Internet Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure about the PyQt5Agg aspects nor matplotlib related stuff, as I am not sure it is openGL compatible.

For the rest, it is a matter of checking wether your have the right plugins installed, for instance, for me it is

```
ls venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/
```

returns

> libqeglfs.so libqminimalegl.so libqoffscreen.so libqwayland-egl.so
> libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so ***libqwebgl.so*** libqlinuxfb.so
> libqminimal.so libqvnc.so libqwayland-generic.so
> libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so libqxcb.so

Now you can try:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=webgl:port=8998 python ./test.py
```

Other environment variables might also help for debugging in general with Qt:

```
export QSG_INFO=1
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_DEBUG=1
export QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.qpa.*=true
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.